# Add html blocks

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have an asp.net web form that gathers details about clinics and patients. On the bottom part of the form i have a block that basically asks for patient information (firstname,lastname, address etc)
I can have n number of patients (n can range from 1 to 10) .
I was thinking i would write one html block and ask a question like

Add another patient?

where i would have to dynamically generate a similar block like the first one with unique id's .

Whats the best approach to this type of problem? How do i deal with validation?

Thanks

Comment: which asp.net framework are you using? is it WebForms or MVC? if Webforms then it makes it alot harder.

Comment: The best approach is the one that satisfies your users while keeping a good maintainability level. There's no really "best" way to achieve this. Try several ways, compare the pro and cons of each and then choose. Return here if you have a specific issue you require help with. Please read the [faq] and [ask] pages.

Comment: I am using asp.net webforms. I understand that there may not be a best way, but just hoping for some suggestions/thoughts about how the other users approached this.

Answer (score 2):

use the `$.clone` method

here is an example

http://jsfiddle.net/eTh2f/1/

make sure you don't use ID though , cuz you will end up with duplicate ids

---

### Update :

- i see that you dont really understand the concept in here .
  ID's are ment to be unique (think of it as a government ID number ) not two can have the same ID.
- while classes are not unique (just like names , many people share the same name ) , they can be assigned to more than one element .

### when to use which

use id's for elements that should never be repeated on the same page .
for example the main header can have an id of `id="header_container"` . While the items of a list  can never have the same id because they are not unique (notice that we are talking about the tag not it's content).

### examples

for id's the header should be ok . so :

```
<div id="header">... header contents ...</div>
```

and for classes a list of items should be ok too

```
<ul>
    <li class="someone" > me <li>
    <li class="someone" > you <li>
    <li class="someone" > he <li>
</ul>
```

you **CAN NOT** do :

```
<ul>
    <li id="someone" > me <li>
    <li id="someone" > you <li>
    <li id="someone" > he <li>
</ul>
```

### back to jquery

you can use any type of valid css selector in jquery

so if i were to get the header i will use

```
$('#header')
```

where 
`#` is the sign for id

and if i were to select **ALL** the list items

```
$('.someone')
```

where
`.` is the sign for id

### what will happen if you use multiple ID's

first of all you should know  that the use of id's is not a really smart idea . i rarely use them (if you can avoid the trouble then do ) .

so use classes . because they can be still only assigned to one element if you do so .
or use the new `data` attribute .

but if you are 100% sure that they will never repeat then use them . example of that is a set of records in the database . sure thing they dont have the same id then just use the attribute id for the elements.

### how can i select a text box in jquery

well simply assign a class . if you dont want to then simply

```
$('input')
```

which will select all the input tags , still a bit inconvenient though , but no worries.
you can select an input by it's name via

```
$('input[name="the_name_of_the_input"]')
```

### Finally

please read more about the topic by googling it . i just append to have a free time . so i invested it . but work hard to get the answer thats how it sticks

Comment: @cableload are the ids important? are they needed at all? generally when i see an ID that needs a number after it to make it unique, that means the id probably should have been a className.

Comment: Kevin, Can you please explain? How can i validate that particular element without using ID? are you trying to say use different classnames and thats good enough to identify which block they belong to?

Comment: how can i access a textbox server control code behind without its ID property? Will i be able to just use the parent div class and identify? can you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use multiple HTML inputs, like:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]"/>
```

Then, in your JavaScript you just append, or clone like the other guy said, the fields! Than you can easily validate in your server side, because every field in your form will be an array, like

`(name[0] = 'patient1', name[1] = 'patient2', etc)`.

Count the number of inputs, and then validate they.