# Jquery selectors - this vs id vs class

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, this

I have an outer div that when I hover over it I want the second child elements to toggle a class in jquery. I believe that I have the code close, I think the problem that I'm having has to do with what I'm selecting and not getting the right selector since I don't fully understand the difference between id, class, or this. Thanks you for your help! (I can't just assign them all to a class since there will be multiple blocks of this same code)

```
<script>
function color_toggle(id){

     selection = $(this) + ' img:nth-child(2)';
     $( selection ).toggleClass("grey");
}
</script>



<div class="row-fluid supplier_new" onmouseover="color_toggle(this);" onmouseout="color_toggle(this);">
        <div class="span3 supplier_logo">
             <h4>APV Manufacturing</h4>
            <img class="grey" src = "img/suppliers/55555/logo.png" />
        </div>

        <div class="span1" style="padding-left:15px;">
            <img class="grey" src="http://aerofied.com/sites/all/themes/aerofied/css/images/icon-verified.png">
            <br><br>
            <img class="grey" src="http://aerofied.com/sites/all/themes/aerofied/css/images/icon-preferred.png">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're passing `this` to the function as the `id` argument, then you want `$(id)`.

However you could call it like this:

```
onmouseover="color_toggle($(this))"
```

And just use `id.find("img:eq(2)").toggleClass("gray")`

Or you could do this:

```
onmouseover="color_toggle.call(this);"
```

And your JS:

```
function color_toggle() {
    $(this).find("img:eq(2)").toggleClass("gray");
}
```

Or you could just use CSS:

```
.someclass:hover img:nth-child(2) {
    /* apply style here */
}
```

Comment: This covers it well. I'd add that `id` is probably a bad name for the parameter, because what is being passed in is not the `id` of the hovered element, but an object representing the element itself. You might call it `target`, or `div`, or `hovered_item`.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

(1) Added ID attributes to `<img>` elements in your code (they were missing)

(2) Removed the inline javascript, used jQuery in script tags (always best to do this)

(3) Fixed jQuery selector:

```
$(this).find('img:eq(2)').attr('id');  // <-- But the ID attr has to EXIST
```

---

<kbd>**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9F4g4/)**</kbd>

In the above jsFiddle demo, you will see the background around the third image go on/off as you mouse over the DIV.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.row-fluid').hover(
            function() {
                hovIn($(this));
            }, 
            function() {
                hovOut($(this));
            }
        );

        function hovIn($this){
            //$this.css({'background':'wheat'});
            var myId = $this.find('img:eq(2)').attr('id');
            color_toggle( myId );
        }
        function hovOut($this){
            //$this.css({'background':'white'});
            var myId = $this.find('img:eq(2)').attr('id');
            color_toggle( myId );
        }
        function color_toggle(id) {
            $('#'+id).toggleClass("grey");
        }

    }); //END document.ready
</script>
```

Since we are using jQuery, ensure you reference the jQuery library (usually in the `<head>` tags at top of page):

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

---

NOTE:

You should print/memorize [this list of jQuery selectors and events](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp). Click `Next Chapter` six times and you will loop through all the pages.

Answer (score 1):

i just updated an answer a secound ago please check the update here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19227334/1743214

so i will just explain this , and when to use it .
this would be just like pointing at something ..

- you cant point at something that is not there . or just went out .
- it has to be there other wise you are `doing_it_wrong()`.

### When do i use `this`

i will cover the basic cases here (so it's not the full answer ).
use `this` when your applying a function over an element.

so lets say im hiding an element .

```
$('#header').hide(5000 , function(){
    $(this) //in this case im pointing at header . because it is the element i have selected . 
})
```

### why use it , let's just use the id again ?!

it would work in the previous example , but take a look at this one

```
<ul>
    <li class="someone" > me <li>
    <li class="someone" > you <li>
    <li class="someone" > he <li>
</ul>

$.each($('.someone'), function(){
    $('.someone') // this will jsut select all the 3 elements again
    $(this) // will get the current element that we are looping though
    // if i do
    console.log($(this).text()) // this will log me then you  then he
})
```

dig deeper about `this` , google topics or read some books :) .